# Padrões para autorização/permissão de usuários

Tags: c#, .net, segurança

Existem outros padrões para autorização/permissão de usuário diferentes do padrão Role-based access control implementado pela Microsoft para tecnologias .NET?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pela Microsoft, há basicamente 3 maneiras de padrão de Design para permissões:

- Por Roles;
- Por Claims;
- Por algum outro padrão implementado pelo usuário (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms729794.aspx)

O padrão mais difundido é o *Role-Based*, justamente porque até o surgimento do ASP.NET Identity o padrão utilizando até o MVC4 era o *Membership* e suas variantes (*Simple Membership*, *Extended Membership*, e assim por diante).

O padrão *Claims-Based* surgiu com o ASP.NET Identity, em que foi repensada toda a estrutura de autenticação, fragmentando ao máximo a identidade do usuário. Uma *Claim* (**reinivindicação**, em tradução livre), é uma fração da identidade do usuário que contém uma identificação e uma chave de acesso criptografada. Através disso, este fragmento de permissão dá o direito ao usuário de reivindicar acesso a uma determinada parte do sistema.

[Há também este post bem interessante](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/05/24/dont-do-role-based-authorization-checks-do-activity-based-checks/) que discute largamente os problemas do padrão *Role-Based*, e sugere uma implementação *Activity-Based*, que seria uma variação simplificada do padrão *Claims-Based*.

Answer (score 1):

Isso depende da tecnologia que você está utilizando. Caso você esteja utilizando MVC, eu indicaria voce customizar uma classe e especificar as roles, por exemplo a classe AuthorizeAttribute(System.Web.Mvc).

Nesse link explica certinho e tem alguns exemplos:

[AuthorizeAttribute Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx)